# How to properly read color using openGL on Android ? (color picking)

Tags: android, colors, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

My problem is a bit odd. I've read a lot of articles and I'm convinced that my code should return my a 3 (or 4 based on settings) float values in range 0 to 1. Than I should convert them to RGB. BUT

```
gl.glReadPixels(screenWidth - this.x, this.y, 1, 1, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
```

byte[] bb = new byte[3];

this code returns values like this

```
{ -9, -7, -7 }
```

I do not know how to get RGB color from this. I've tried multipling, dividing and so on and so on. My code is exactly the same like in 99% of examples in code but still I'm receiving really strange values.

The whole goal is to pick color of touched point on screen

// UPDATE

```
ByteBuffer pixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3);
        pixelBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        gl.glReadPixels(screenWidth - this.x, this.y, 1, 1, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

        byte[] bb = new byte[3];
        pixelBuffer.get(bb);
        String key = bb[0] + " " + bb[1] + " " + bb[2];
        Log.d("KOLOR", key);
        String colorName = "";

            float r = (float)pixelBuffer.get(0);
            float g = (float)pixelBuffer.get(1);
            float b = (float)pixelBuffer.get(2);


        takeScreenshot = false;
```

For example when I "picked" red color values for variables r,g,b where: -1.0, 36.0, 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in your code, you try to retrieve an `UNSIGNED BYTE`:

```
 GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
```

And you assign this to: A byte (-array). And from your result I can see, that this byte is not an unsigned one.

What happens when you assign a value like 245 to a signed byte? Its binary value gets interpreted as a signed number, with the highest bit being the sign, so `{-9, -7, -7}` in an unsigned byte context should be `{245,247,247}` if I'm not mistaken.

In Java, all primitive integer types are signed, there is no way around that.

So what you may want to do, is creating a second array containing the (correct) integer values:

```
int[] ib = new int[3];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    ib[i] = (int)((int)bb[i] & 0xff);
```

and then output that result.

```
String key = ib[0] + " " + ib[1] + " " + ib[2];
```

Also, you should change that part of the code:

```
float r = (float)pixelBuffer.get(0);
float g = (float)pixelBuffer.get(1);
float b = (float)pixelBuffer.get(2);
```

to

```
float r = ib[0]/255.0f;
float g = ib[1]/255.0f;
float b = ib[2]/255.0f;
```

Because, as soon as you start using the color values as `float`s, you want them aligned between 0 and 1

Comment: I was thinking about that and I've tried different types. For example I've changed it to 'GL10.GL_FLOAT' but nothing works. Funny thing is that the case with unsigned_byte is taken from every tutorial in web

Comment: No, your function call is correct. You just use the result the wrong way. Provide some code where you assign the result of the function call to your byte-array and where you see the output and I may be able to help more explicitly

Comment: I've updated my code. I've also put there example data that are returned for specific variables were I want to have info about color index

Comment: Thank you but what is `b` variable ? Shouldn't it be `bb[i]` ?