# How to detect click on objects in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need the program to detect when I click on the drawn object
How can this be done in OpenGL ES?
I get an array of coordinates and draw them on the field. I should be able to click on rendered points, but I don't know how to do it
Render code below

My points array and buffer array

```
 var ppl: Array<FloatArray> = arrayOf(
        floatArrayOf(30f,1f,0f,0f,0f,1f),  ///x,y,z,isActive,isWork,signal
        floatArrayOf(-10f,10f,0f,1f,1f,1f),
        floatArrayOf(0f,0f,0f,1f,0f,0f),
        floatArrayOf(70f,50f,50f,1f,0f,1f)
    )

var mBufferLen = intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) //0/Floor/Floor2/Point/Ball/Drop/Grid/Size/Search/Work
```

My onSurfaceCreated fun

```
    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl1: GL10, pConfig: javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig?) {
        val gl = gl1 as GL11 //we need 1.1 functionality
        //set background frame color
        //gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING)
        gl.glClearColor(0.01f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f) //dark-green
        BuildDrop(gl)
        BuildFloor2(gl)
        BuildFloor(gl)
        BuildGrid(gl)
        BuildSizeGrid(gl, spinnerIndicator)
        BuildDropT(gl)
        BuildWorkMark(gl)
    }
```

My BuildDrop fun

```
    fun BuildDrop(gl: GL11) {
        //every drop has the same coordinates
        //we glRotate and glTranslate when drawing
        val vtx = floatArrayOf(
            // X, Y, Z
            0f, 0f, 0f,
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,
            0f, -2f, 0f,
        )
        StoreVertexData(gl, vtx, mDROP) //store in GPU buffer
    }
```

Store Vertex fun

```
    fun StoreVertexData(gl: GL11, pVertices: FloatArray, pObjectNum: Int) {
        val buffer: FloatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pVertices.size * 4) //float is 4 bytes
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()) // use the device hardware's native byte order
            .asFloatBuffer() // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
            .put(pVertices) // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pObjectNum) //bind as current object
        buffer.position(0)
        //allocate memory and write buffer data
        gl.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.capacity() * 4, buffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) //unbind from buffer
        mBufferLen[pObjectNum] = buffer.capacity() / 3 //store for drawing
    }
```

My fun for Drawing points

```
    private fun DrawDropMarks(gl: GL11, pDropCoords: Array<FloatArray>) {
        var pDropCoords = pDropCoords
        var pAngX = 0f
        var pAngY = 0f
        val TriCnt = pDropCoords.size //triangle count
        var isActive = 10f
        var isWork = 10f
        var signal = 10f
        val centerX = (display.width/2)
        val centerY = (display.height/2)
        for (ctr in 0 until TriCnt) {
            gl.glColor4f(1f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f) // mark default color
            gl.glPushMatrix() //translate\rotate only affects this single triangle
            gl.glTranslatef(centerX.toFloat(), centerY.toFloat(), 0f)
            //gl.glTranslatef(pDropCoords[ctr][0], pDropCoords[ctr][1], pDropCoords[ctr][2])
            if (MultiBillboard) //calc each triangle billboard angle separately
            {
                var hypLen: Float
                val distX = mCamXpos - pDropCoords[ctr][0]
                val distY = mCamYpos - pDropCoords[ctr][1]
                val distZ = mCamZpos - pDropCoords[ctr][2]
                isActive = pDropCoords[ctr][3]
                isWork = pDropCoords[ctr][4]
                signal = pDropCoords[ctr][5]
                //hypotenuse in 2D
                hypLen = sqrt((distX * distX + distZ * distZ).toDouble()).toFloat() //across floor
                pAngY = 270 - atan2(distZ.toDouble(), distX.toDouble()).toFloat() * mRad2Deg.toFloat()
                //3rd dimension
                pAngX = atan2(distY.toDouble(), hypLen.toDouble()).toFloat() * mRad2Deg.toFloat()
/*                Log.d("x",pAngX.toString())
                Log.d("y",pAngY.toString())
                Log.d("hyp",hypLen.toString())*/
            }
            gl.glRotatef(pAngY, 0f, 1f, 0f)
            gl.glRotatef(pAngX, 1f, 0f, 0f)
            mark = (sin((System.currentTimeMillis() * 2 * Math.PI / FLASH_DURATION) * 0.5) + 0.5)
            //size of triangles
            gl.glScalef(lengthRatio, lengthRatio, lengthRatio)
            if (signal == 0f){
                ppl = remove(ppl,ctr)
                pl += pDropCoords[ctr]
            }
            if ((isActive == 1f)){
                //initialize vertex Buffer for triangle
                gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
                gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mSEARCH)
                gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
                if (isWork == 0f) {
                    gl.glColor4f(0.3f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f)
                }
                else gl.glColor4f(1f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f)// active mark color
                //gl.glColor4f(0.3f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f) // active mark color
                gl.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_LINES, 0, mBufferLen[mSEARCH])
            } //single drop
            if ((isWork == 1f) && (isActive == 1f)){
                //initialize vertex Buffer for triangle
                gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
                gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mWORK)
                gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
                gl.glColor4f(1f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f) // active mark color
                //gl.glColor4f(0.3f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f) // active mark color
                gl.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_LINES, 0, mBufferLen[mWORK])
            } //single drop
            gl.glPopMatrix() //done with this triangle
        }
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) //unbind from buffer
    }
```

Im new in opengl
I tried to detect click in onTouch event but coordinates in onTouchEvent and my coordinates are different. I also read about the ray-picking algorithm, but is there some simpler way to detect clicking on objects in opengl es?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will be a bit broad. There are two general ways of detecting clicks.

1. Drawing all objects to a separate framebuffer, each object in distinct colors and reading the pixel color from the buffer.

   Pros: fairly easy to implement
   Cons: reading from the framebuffer is slow.
   Read more about it [here](https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-an-opengl-hack/) and maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42877963/971972)
2. Ray-picking (as you've said)

There are pros and cons to both methods. In my projects I always went for 1. It involves some math, but that's what OpenGL is about. I can't describe the math here, but I might be able to give you some pointers.

Also you might want to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 fairly soon. There is some benefit of learning the fixed function pipeline (it's a bit easier), but 2.0 has way more features and is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't understand some things about both algorithms
1) According to the first algorithm. If I don’t know how many objects I will draw (objects will come to me dynamically), and I also need to know exactly which object I click on, then I must increment the color of each new incoming object (for example, at 0.0001) and immediately associate this object with this color?
2) and according to the second algorithm. Do you know where I can see examples of using this algorithm or read a good theory?

Comment: I mean, you always know which objects you will draw in the current frame, right? And you'd want to increase the color by 1.0/256.0, because the color buffer is usually 8 bits per color. I added a link to a good tutorial to my answer.